# Hyperlinks are not working in excel sheet in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, excel, hyperlink

I have uploaded the excel sheet on my sharepoint site.it is opening in a webpart. I have some hyperlinks columns in my sheet. But when i trying to access the hyperlink it is not navigate. why ?
In my excel sheet whet it is opening in MS office it is working fine.

Comment: (I have merged the repost; don't do that please)

Comment: I had the same issue using Sharepoint 2013.  It didn't matter how I created the link in Excel, it would look like a link but was unclickable (using ctrl+click or any other combination).

The only way I was able to add a working link was to open the spreadsheet in the Sharepoint Excel Web Access editor.  Once the spreadsheet is open, select Insert->Hyperlink, add your link & description and then save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do the unchecking of the "Update links on save" checkbox BEFORE adding hyperlinks, only then it works. Please follow these steps:

1. Save the excel file to your local machine.
2. Delete existing hyperlinks, if any.
3. Now in Excel go to Options and under General tab click Web Options and on the Files tab uncheck the "Update links on save". Click ok.
4. After this add the hyperlinks again.
5. Publish and put the excel workbook on the SharePoint server in whichever folder references your excel web part.
6. Close IE. Now open IE and ur web page on SharePoint. See it work !

Answer (score 3):

Use the excel formula `=Hyperlink(Link Address, [Friendly Name])` instead of the embedding the hyperlink in the text.

Comment: this is the answer in 2016

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Excel Web Access (displaying your Excel as a web page) AFAIK it does not support (it does not render) links.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try holding down the control (ctrl) key when you click on the hyperlinks?

Comment: It's a sharepoint website. it doesn't actually matter if you hold the control key. This would work in a doc or xls file but not in a web part in sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things that you should check out in the control pane of the web part are if the checkboxes for Hyperlinks and Navigation are checked.

But, unfortunately, this did not solve my problem.

Another thing you could do is, in Excel go to Options and under General tab click Web Options and on the Files tab uncheck the "Update links on save".

Unfortunately this did not solve my problem either.

Answer (score -1):

On your list page do the following:

1. Click on settings -> list settings
2. Click create column
3. Change type to Hyperlink or Picture -> OK
4. Open your excel file and copy the links to the new column.

I think this should work but it is untested.

Comment: If this or another posts answers your question, please mark it as "answered"